# Formulario HTML a Google Drive funciona pero no da mensaje de confirmación

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

cree una App con el script de spreadsheets de Google Drive, tengo un form html y este envía correctamente los datos a mi hoja de calculo en Drive, pero no logro hacer que se muestre el mensaje "Enviado" o que cuando se complete me redirige a otro sitio web:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>app 1</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 


 <form name="contact" >  
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Nombres">  
  <input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos">  
  <input type="mobile" name="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>  
 </form>  
 <script>  
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzR5fKcxPjmNMnrk6XNWxa0c68gwURI5tXxw96hpeKI3s17AFLW/exec'  
  const form = document.forms['contact']  
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {  
   e.preventDefault()  
   fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})  
    .then(response => console.log('Enviado!', response))  
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))  
  })  
 </script> 


 </body>
 </html>
```

```
var sheetName = 'app'  
 var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()  
 function intialSetup () {  
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()  
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())  
 }  
 function doPost (e) {  
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()  
  lock.tryLock(10000)  
  try {  
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))  
   var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)  
   var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]  
   var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1  
   var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {  
    return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]  
   })  
   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])  
   return ContentService  
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))  
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)  
  }  
  catch (e) {  
   return ContentService  
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))  
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)  
  }  
  finally {  
   lock.releaseLock()  
  }  

 }
```

Comment: Aquí sí se muestra el mensaje `Enviado!`

Comment: En la primera revisión de la pregunta colocaste el código en Stack Snippet, este agrega un botón Ejecutar. En mi comentario previo me refería que al hacer clic en dicho botón la consola muestra `Enviado!`. He visto que has agregado el código de tu web app. Te sugiero ampliar la narrativa de la pregunta para hacer claro donde quieres ver `Enviado!` así como el rol de cada parte del código (al menos señala cuál es el código del lado cliente y cuál del lado del servidor).

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta parcial

El código en la pregunta está cargado dos versiones de jQuery distintas, lo peor es que primero se carga la versión más reciente y luego la antigua así que la antigua "cancela" las mejoras de la mas reciente de los métodos que se llaman igual.

Solución usa sólo una versión de jQuery.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, ya lo hice pero sigue igual, intercambié las dos versiones de jQuery pero no funcionó

Comment: @Uniagustina como te mencionaba en un comentario a la pregunta, el código que colocaste en Stack Snippet muestra `Enviado!`.