# como puedo copiar valores de inputs en clipboard desde un formulario google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Alguien sabe como puedo copiar los valores de los inputs, es decir, los textos ingresados y sus labels, o bien solo los contenidos sin los labels, al clipboard para pegarlos en un archivo de texto antes de guardar?
Hasta el momento no encuentro ningún tutorial sobre copiar contenidos de inputs de forma directa, sin seleccionar previamente, y yo quiero que se autoseleccionen determinados inputs con un botón y se copie sus contenidos al clipboard.-

```html
<div class= "container">  
    
   <h4><?= title; ?></h4>

    
         <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="fechaasig">Fecha Asig.</label> <input disabled id="fechaasig" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="deudatotalmadura">Total</label> <input disabled id="deudatotalmadura" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="carteraasig">Cartera</label> <input disabled id="carteraasig" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s2">
          <label for="fechahoy">Hoy</label> <input disabled id="fechahoy" type="text" class="validate">          
          </div>
          </div><!--CLOSE ROW -->
          </div><!--CLOSE CONTAINER -->
```

Tengo este script, que me hizo un amigo para un formulario html que tengo, que me permite copiar de forma directa con el boton, los inputs que yo decido en la función, esto sería lo ideal, pero no sé como pasarlo a google app script

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $('#conquita').on('click', function(e){
    var el = $(this);
    var pluralsinquita = parseInt($('#numeroCuotassinquita').val()) == 1 ? '' : 's';
    var plural = parseInt($('#numeroCuotas').val()) == 1 ? '' : 's';
    var temp = $("<textarea>");
    $("body").append(temp);

    //Copia SALDO TOTAL EN 1 PAGO
    var cancelacionunpago = 'Sobre Saldo: $'+$('#deudaengage').val()+
    '\r\nMonto Descuento: $'+$('#descuento').val()+' '+ $('#quita').val()+ '%'+
    '\r\nSaldo Final: $'+$('#saldoFinal').val();

    
    var cancelacionconquita = 'Sobre Saldo: $'+$('#deudaengage').val()+
    '\r\nMonto Descuento: $'+$('#descuento').val() +' '+ $('#quita').val()+ '%'+
    '\r\nSaldo Final: $'+$('#saldoFinal').val()+
    '\r\nCantidad de Cuotas: '+$('#numeroCuotas').val()+
    '\r\nImporte Cuotas: $'+$('#importeCuotas').val();
    
    
    // concatenar los dos totales en un solo string con nombre content, que es el copiado al portapapeles
    var content = 'SALDo' + 
    '\r\ncliente'+
    '\r\nPAGO CANCELATORIOS: ' + '\r\n'+ cancelacionunpago+
    '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
    'SALDO' + 
    '\r\ncliente'+
    '\r\nCUOTAS FIJAS: ' + '\r\n'+ cancelacionconquita;
    
    temp.val(content).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    temp.remove();
    el.text('Copiado!');
    el.removeClass('btn-warning');
    el.addClass('btn-success');
    setTimeout(function(texto){
      el.text(texto);
      el.removeClass('btn-success');
      el.addClass('btn-warning');
    }, 1000, 'Copiar')

    }); 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no es coherente, al principio dice que no se quiere seleccionar los inputs pero el ejemplo de tu amigo dices "los inputs que yo decido", también se menciona que nos sabes como pasarlo a Google Apps Script. Esto denota que te hacen falta algunos conceptos básicos así que a continuación se hacen algunas observaciones, empezando por el segundo código:

1. Este está usando funciones `$()` lo cual es una característica distintiva de jQuery, un *framework* muy popular de JavaScript.
2. El código está incompleto ya que no no carga una librería de jQuery la cual es necesaria para que funcione.
3. Como ejemplo está incompleto pues no include HTML

Sobre Google Apps Script

Se puede usar `jQuery` en el código del lado del cliente del Google Apps Script (cuando se usa el HTMLService) pero no se recomienda usarlo ciegamente porque podría afectar negativamente el desempeño de aplicación ya que el podrías estar agregando capacidades que tu aplicación no se requieren. Si decides usarlo, en el código del lado del cliente debe incluirse la carga de la librería de jQuery a usar lo cual puede hacerse de la misma forma que se hace en una página web básica.

En cuanto a enviar los inputs sin tener que seleccionarlos, esto es posible. Para ello debes incluir un formulario en tu HTML, dentro de estos los input y enviar al código del lado del servidor el objeto formulario. En las guías de la documentación oficial se include un ejemplo de uso de formulario e incluso del uso de una librería de jQuery. Te dejo los enlaces a la introducción y a la sección específica del uso de formularios, y a las mejores prácticas que incluyen un ejemplo que usa jQuery.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Relacionado

- [Cómo usar jQuery Ajax POST con Google Apps Script para mostrar una página de agradecimiento personalizada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65908/65)
- [¿Se debería usar jQuery en "toda" aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/82254/65)
- [Formulario HTML a Google Drive funciona pero no da mensaje de confirmación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/194337/65)

Comment: Hola, Sin seleccionar previamente me refiero, a hacer la selección manual, lógicamente necesito elegir que inputs quiero que se copien, pero desde la programación y no por una acción manual.-  Dicho esto, muchas veces veo que las preguntas se responden de una manera agresiva sobre el conocimiento o desconocimiento que una persona puede tener... Estimo que los que responden, nacieron sabiendo y fueron siempre conocedores de la programación de forma tal, que este tipo de respuestas, es obvio que se siguen como si nada en los links, previo a indicar que está claro que no sé como es el tema...

Comment: Siempre pienso que el día que alguien me consulte sobre algo que sé muy bien y el otro no, buscaré como ayudarle en todo sentido y no solo respondiendo lo que tranquilamente se busca en google, que son miles de links y tutoriales para aprender solo.- Disculpen, pensé que en los foros de ayuda se ayudaba, no que me decían que leer y que tutorial mirar.- Por cierto, no incluí toda la información, porque pensé que para el que sabe mucho, ver ese parcial del código sin Html, entendería lo que estoy buscando.-

Comment: Gracias, por nada puntual, seguiré viendo en Youtube la gente que se toma el tiempo de explicar a los que no sabemos nada y molestamos en los foros? .- Saludos.- May the force be with you

Comment: 1. Si no lo has hecho aún por favor lee [ask] , [mcve] y [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 2. Si estás de acuerdo de que tu pregunta no es del todo clara o que puede mejorar, por favor edítala, pero si tienes una pregunta de seguimiento publica una nueva. 3. A muchos de los que participamos regularmente en sitios de [se] no nos gusta que se les llame foro pues el modelo de este sitio surgió para evitar problemas de los predecesores como lo son el que se pregunta una y otra vez lo mismo, entre otros tantos. ¡Ánimo!